# Strange behaviour of Python script

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have to extract start date, start time and end date, end time in desired format from a string in python. For that I wrote a code:

```
from datetime import *


#date_time = 'Sun Apr 22 2018 at 02:00 pm to Sun May 13 2018 at 02:00 pm'
#date_time = 'Sun Apr 22 2018 at 02:00 pm'
#date_time = 'Sat Apr 28 2018 at 05:00 pm to 07:00 am'  
#date_time = 'Fri Oct 15 2021'

date_time = 'Sat Aug 01 2020'
#date_time = 'Wed Jan 22 2020 at 01:30 pm'

#date_time = 'Wed Jan 01 2020 to Thu Jan 02 2020'   

delim = 'to'

if delim in date_time:
   start_date_time = date_time.split(delim, 2)[0]
   start_date_time = start_date_time.partition(' ')[2] #remove the first word of the string

   end_date_time = date_time.split(delim, 2)[1]
   end_date_time = end_date_time.strip() #remove the first space in the string
   #end_date_time = end_date_time.partition(' ')[2] #remove the first word of the string

   delim = 'at'

   start_date = start_date_time.split(delim, 2)[0]
   start_date = start_date.rstrip() #remove the space at the end of the string
   start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%b %d %Y")

   start_time = start_date_time.split(delim, 2)[1]
   start_time = start_time.strip()
   start_time = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%I:%M %p")
   start_time = datetime.strftime(start_time, "%H:%M:%S")

   if delim in end_date_time:
      end_date_time = end_date_time.partition(' ')[2] #remove the first word of the string
      end_date = end_date_time.split(delim, 2)[0]
      #print(end_date)
      end_date = end_date.rstrip()
      end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%b %d %Y")
      #print(end_date)

      end_time = end_date_time.split(delim, 2)[1]
      end_time = end_time.strip()
      end_time = datetime.strptime(end_time, "%I:%M %p")
      end_time = datetime.strftime(end_time, "%H:%M:%S")

   else:   
      end_date = start_date
      end_time = end_date_time
      end_time = end_time.strip()
      end_time = end_time.rstrip()
      end_time = datetime.strptime(end_time, "%I:%M %p")
      end_time = datetime.strftime(end_time, "%H:%M:%S")
else: 

   delim = 'at'

   if delim in date_time:
      start_date_time = date_time.partition(' ')[2]
      #end_date_time = start_date_time

      #delim = 'at'

      start_date = start_date_time.split(delim, 2)[0]
      start_date = start_date.rstrip() 
      start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%b %d %Y")

      start_time = start_date_time.split(delim, 2)[1]
      start_time = start_time.strip()
      start_time = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%I:%M %p")
      start_time = datetime.strftime(start_time, "%H:%M:%S")

      #end_date = end_date_time.split(delim, 2)[0]
      #print(end_date)
      #end_date = end_date.rstrip()
      #end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%b %d %Y")
      #print(end_date)
      end_date = start_date
      end_time = ''

   else:
      start_date_time = date_time.partition(' ')[2]
      #end_date_time = start_date_time 

      #start_date = start_date_time.split(delim, 2)[0]
      start_date = start_date_time.rstrip() 
      start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%b %d %Y")

      start_time = ''

      end_date = start_date
      end_time = ''




'''delim = 'at'

start_date = start_date_time.split(delim, 2)[0]
start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%b %d %Y ")

start_time = start_date_time.split(delim, 2)[1]
start_time = start_time.strip()
start_time = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%I:%M %p")
start_time = datetime.strftime(start_time, "%H:%M:%S")

end_date = end_date_time.split(delim, 2)[0]
end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%b %d %Y ")

end_time = end_date_time.split(delim, 2)[1]
end_time = end_time.strip()
end_time = datetime.strptime(end_time, "%I:%M %p")
end_time = datetime.strftime(end_time, "%H:%M:%S")'''


#print(start_date_time)
print(start_date)
print(start_time)
print('-'*40)
#print(end_date_time)
print(end_date)
print(end_time)
```

for `date_time = 'Fri Oct 15 2021'` , it's producing correct output as:

```
$ python date_time.py
2021-10-15 00:00:00

----------------------------------------
2021-10-15 00:00:00
```

But for another similar string `date_time = 'Sat Aug 01 2020'`, it's generating error:

```
$ python date_time.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "date_time.py", line 69, in <module>
    start_time = start_date_time.split(delim, 2)[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I can't debug the code.

Comment: You *did* notice that "Sat" contains "at", right?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : OMG!!!!! Thank you very much. I changed Sat to Sun and it worked. How to handle this problematic 'Sat'? Any suggestion?

Comment: Either use regexp or do not destroy delimiting spaces so greedily, and match " at ".  This would not match Sat.

Comment: Why not just use `strptime` to convert the written time back into a `datetime`?

Comment: That is what he finally does, but it needs to cater for "to" and "at" keywords as well and be able to parse those before finding the part that can be strptimed.

Comment: I just changed  ** delim = 'at' ** to ** delim = ' at ' ** and it's working now. Thanks all. :)